# max-width css property stops centered div from working in internet explorer?

Tags: html, css

I have a navbar div inside a parent which is horizontally centered/resizes to be responsive using the following css:

```
.navbar-parent-wrapper{
    width: 100%;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.navbar-child-wrapper{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    max-width:1200px;
    padding-top:10px; 
}
```

however the max-width property seems to stop my navbar from being centered in internet explorer and causes it to float to the left(works on all other browsers). If i change max-width to width, it works, but stops auto re-sizing to be responsive.

Is there a work around for this?

Comment: Your `max-width` and `left/right` properties are in conflict. The absolute positioning is taking precedence here. Why do you need the absolute position? Some more context would be helpful.

Comment: the navbar currently floats on top of a slider div which is why i used the absolute positioning

Answer (score 2):

Try it

```
.navbar-child-wrapper{
        position: relative;
        margin: 0 auto;
        max-width:1200px;
        padding-top:10px; 
    }
```

Comment: I should have mentioned, the navbar currently floats on top of a slider div which is why i used absolute positioning. The above code centered the navbar but pushed away the slider. Is there any way to do this using absolute position?

Comment: This doesn't work, navbar needs to be fixed at the top.